# How to reduce the page height of the bootstrap template?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the template shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). I want to reduce the height of the page.

I tried

```
body{ max-height:800px;}
```

and

```
html{max-height:800px;}
```

but nothing seems to be making a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `min-height` of the `body` tag.

Try this :

```
body{ 
    min-height:800px;
}
```

Comment: It should.Because it is working for me.Set `min-height:800px;` and `max-height:1000px;`.

Comment: shall I attach my bootstrap.css ?

Comment: Yes.I need to look your CSS for that.

Comment: the css file is too big.. is there an option to upload file here?

Comment: You can use [pastebin](pastebin.com).

Comment: Its here : http://pastebin.com/7Z0LcUQE   there are two body sections.in second section I have added what you suggested.

Comment: Its working when I add this code : `body {
      margin: 0;
   min-height:1000px;
   max-height:2000px;
        }`